# Как проверить согласованность таблиц при помощи хранимой процедуры?

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток :)

Есть некоторая БД, в которой существуют две таблицы: **сотрудник** и **отдел**. В таблице сотрудник хранится информация о сотруднике, что логично, а в таблице отдел, помимо еще кучи полей, есть поле, в котором указано **количество сотрудников** какого-либо отдела. Заданием является написание триггера, который вносит изменение в поле **"Количество сотрудников"** после добавление нового сотрудника в таблицу **"Сотрудники"**.
Если коротко, то: *добавил сотрудника, с помощью триггера увеличь на 1 кол-во сотрудников в другой таблице*.
И появился такой нюанс, если изначально таблицы рассогласованна ( *в таблице "Сотрудники" 20 человек из отдела X, а в таблице "Отдел" в поле количество сотрудников их всего, например, 6*), то как, при помощи **хранимой процедуры** согласовать таблицы? Иначе триггеры смысла не имеют, ваш Кэп.

Спасибо за внимание :)

Comment: А почему именно с помощью процедуры, если это делается одним запросом ?

Comment: Того требует задание :)

Answer (score 3):

В указанной задаче написание триггера или процедуры приносит **проблемы** согласованности и лишние сущности для базы данных без логического обоснования данного решения.

Хранить агрегированное количество **требуется только там**, где запрос на выборку занимает продолжительное время. Например, финансовая история и общий баланс по кошельку на основе этой истории. Пару миллионов операций и расчет баланса может превратиться в длительное ожидание, а баланс пользователю надо было показать еще вчера.

Если требуется получить количество сотрудников в отделе, делайте это запросом, примерно следующим:

```
SELECT departament.name, COUNT(*)
FROM departament
JOIN staff ON staff.departament_id = departament.id 
GROUP BY departament.id
```

Избегайте агрегации значений в полях таблиц, и используйте их тогда, когда это действительно увеличивает производительность запросов **в несколько раз**, посредством уменьшения количества и времени выполняемых операций, в других случаях - используйте запросы с использованием индексов.

**UPDATE к комментарию**

Тогда запрос еще проще:

```
 UPDATE departament
SET count =
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM staff
   WHERE departament_id=departament.id)
```

А вот процедура:

```
 DELIMITER //  

CREATE PROCEDURE `correct_count`()  
BEGIN  
         UPDATE departament
SET count =
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM staff
   WHERE departament_id=departament.id)
END//
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ad45/1)

Comment: Шикарный и познавательный ответ, спасибо :) Но дело в том, что я просто студент и мне приходится выполнять данные мне задания. Из задания следует, что должно храниться агрегировнное значение, а все задание именно в написании этой хранимой функции :)

Comment: @Марк, тогда вся ваша хранимая процедура - это вот этот запрос с операцией UPDATE - обновил ответ